# Where form fields data are stored after submitting a FORM in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I always use $_POST and $_GET method to access all information submitted by a form but I want to know where all form data is temporally stored? Is there any buffer through which these super variables are connected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP superglobals $_GET and $_POST are used to collect form-data.

This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.

PHP stores that information automatically into that superglobals (that's the place where are stored).

Superglobals are built-in variables that are always available in all scopes. Please refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

For $_GET and $_POST superglobals information, please refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: I am not asking for global variables , just wanted to know about form data to be stored ?Thanks

Comment: The data from a form is stored automatically into $_GET and $_POST superglobals. That's the "storage". Please refer to the links. You have a lot of information about how this works.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side so wherever your server is that you're sending the information that, it's cached there.

Comment: How it is stored and how it is connected to $_POST and _GET.Please clear more specific.Thanks

Comment: POST and GET are just two methods of sending information. POST silently sends it to the server by attaching it to the HTTP headers and GET sends it through the URL. The data you send is stored on the server in it's temporary memory to be use used by your script in the PHP file. How else can it be described...?

Comment: and How it stores inmemory?I an not getting your point for what I am asking.Thanks

Comment: How deep are you trying to get here? If you want the deep answer it stores it within the operating system into machine code 0's and 1's level. The server has temporary flash memory for holding form data sent to it via requests which are stored within the header information of the request to the associated script (page) you're running. POST and GET are superglobal variables which the server caches..